# Как вывести на консоль одинаковые числа из двух массивов?

Tags: c#, массивы

Например. Я создаю два интовых массива, по 10 элементов каждый. Рандомно присваиваю им значения от 0 до 50. Как вывести на консоль все числа,которые есть и в первом и во втором массиве?(т.е. не обязательно,чтобы индексы совпадали,это важно)

Comment: В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик  в том, что *белые рыцари*, к сожалению, не мамонты (=__=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте Linq-метод расширения [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (var element in array1.Intersect(array2))
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Comment: Да емаё, вы тут дежурите что ли) я только ответ писать начал!

Comment: @Сергей, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Большое спасибо,Андрей. А с помощью цикла for как это сделать?)я написала сначала if (firstArray[i]  == secondArray[i]) ,но так выводятся числа с одинаковыми индексами. извиняюсь за глупые вопросы,ребята

Comment: @LolyPrincess, запускайте 2 вложенных цикла по i и по j и сравнивайте `firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]`

Comment: @АндрейNOP  да,всё вышло. спасибо)